# Polling as a measure to prevent answer flood.

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, voting, polling

Here is an example (speculative) of the question: 
What IDE do you like.

So, shortly we'd see something like:
'VS6 blah-blah..' x500
'blah-blamm VS2010..' x100
'bzzzz Eclipse..' x1000
'vim is cool!' x20
'we use butterflies!'
and so one.

maybe we can find a method to fold such flames? Vote for answers are not enough. Like polling, for example, of smth else. Of course, we should leave the ability to provide full answer in free form, but maybe polling is what we need for the kind of questions I mentioned here.

Comment: Hmm, it might be a nice idea to see answers come in live under the place where you type your answer, maybe a nice idea to suggest on Meta.SO?

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think we should encourage upvoting if you're just likely to say the same thing, to the point that at least here on p.se, we should be looking for down votes on too similar answers if posted more than a couple of minutes apart.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kinda self-correcting.  If there's 10 "VS2010" answers, generally only one (usually one of the first ones) gets voted up significantly.  As such, the relevant and distinct answers tend to rise to the top (assuming you sort by votes).

The downside, of course, is that after a while questions will stagnate as new answers (starting with 1 vote) get lost at the bottom of the thread.